# Tomcat requires restart to take Jasper Reports changes

Tags: spring, tomcat, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Reports as part of my Spring application. I deploy my application on a Tomcat 6 server through eclipse, so my project is a WTP project. The problem I have is that when I change a Jasper Reports file (jrxml) I need to restart the server in order to get the changes published. I already checked on the deployment folder and the .jrxml is updated, but for some reason the browser keeps getting the old report, I already cleaned the cache on the browser without luck.

Any ideas on how to solve this, is super annoying when doing development.

Comment: This isn't a Tomcat issue... it's a JasperReports issue. Are you using JasperServer or did you write your own code to load the `.jrxml` file, compile it, fill it full of data, etc.?

Comment: I added the Spring configuration files to load the .jrxml directly, and I fill the data on a Spring Controller method. Thanks

Comment: So the question is where the file is being cached. It could be in the JasperReports component, in the Spring component, or in Tomcat itself. Tomcat will cache files loaded using any mechanism such as `[Webapp]ClassLoader.findResource`. If you use `FileInputStream` or otherwise fetch the bytes yourself, then the caching is not in Tomcat and you'll have to look elsewhere (i.e. the problem is not Tomcat-specific).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use ireport to change .jrxml, when you save changes in that, the eclipse will not be immediately notified that. So you need to fresh your project in eclipse, if necessary, clean and rebuild the project, and redeploy to tomcat.

Also, you can set eclipse to auto build project (Porject-->check Build automatically) and keep refresh the project. When you see the status 'Synchronized' of your project changes to 'Republic' in the 'Server' View, you can restart the server and see the changes. Press 'ctrl+f5' to fresh the page with refreshing all the cache.

Comment: I don't use iReport, I use JasperSoft Studio inside my Eclipse. So when I change the .jrxml eclipse automatially compiles and deploys it into Tomcat, but tomcat doesn't take the change until I restart it.